# Dropdown menus breaking when parent width undefined

Tags: html, css, format, dropdown, responsive

I've got a navigation bar where the character length of each list item varies substantially. I prefer the visual effect of leaving width on auto and adding padding to defining the same width for each item.

I want my drop downs to inherit the width of their parent list elements. Instead, they're as wide as their own content.

Manually defining the width of each drop down seems like a really inelegant solution, although I've tried it. It's also not particularly responsive.

I've also tried setting ul li ul width to inherit, to no avail.

HTML:

```
  <div id="nav"> <!--nestled in div to provide full view-width bar-->
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1 is medium
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2 is medium
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 3 is very long
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 4 is short
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 7em;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dcdcdc;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul {
  width: inherit;
}

ul li ul li {
  background-color: #181818;
  margin-left: -7em;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

Is there a better solution for setting the drop-downs to the width of their parent list items than manually defining the width of each drop-down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
#nav {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100vw;
}

#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav > ul {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 7em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dcdcdc;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}


#nav > ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul {
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-right: -1em;
     display: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  background-color: #181818;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solved my problem, although I'm still unclear as to why. Could you provide an explanation?

Comment: That was the problem: ul li {float:left}. It affects first level li and submenu level li, and when you set float to child it doesn’t fit parent’s width.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #181818;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 7em;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #dcdcdc;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-table;
}

ul li ul li {
  background-color: #181818;
  margin-left: -7em;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"> <!--nestled in div to provide full view-width bar-->
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1 is medium
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2 is medium
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 3 is very long
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 4 is short
        <ul>
          <li><a>Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

`width: 100%;` and `display: inline-table;` made the true thing

Comment: the snippet is divided into two rows because of your width:100vw; into the nav's css

Comment: I tried this but it spaced out each of my list items equally along the nav bar. Plus the drop-downs appeared off center.Thanks for the answer though!